# Chamar class="button" em vez de id="download"

Tags: javascript

Como faço para esse script funcionar com class="button" em vez de id="download"?

codigo js

```
 var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
 var counter = 10;
 var newElement = document.createElement("p");
 newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
 var id;

 downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);

 id = setInterval(function() {
counter--;
if(counter < 0) {
    newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
    clearInterval(id);
} else {
    newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + 
 counter.toString() + " seconds.";
 }
 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere a primeira linha para:

```
var downloadButton = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
```

Considerando que o botão é o primeiro da classe `.button`. Mesmo que haja outros com a mesma classe, apenas ele será selecionado.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, eu já tinha colocado o document.getElementsByClassName mas não coloquei o [0], dai ele não funcionou, agora está funcionando de boa, vlw :D

Answer (score 0):

Altere na primeira linha:

```
var downloadButton = document.querySelector(".button");
```

Se só houver um elemento com essa classe, vai dar tudo certo. Mas se houver mais de um, vai dar tudo errado.